# Half Float texture failing to attach to a framebuffer

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, framebuffer, render-to-texture

I have 2 devices a Nexus 7 and a Kyocera Hydro Vibe both of which support `GL_OES_texture_half_float` and `EXT_Color_buffer_half_float` however attaching a buffer through

```
    // generate the textures
    int GL_OES_texture_half_float = 0x8D61;
    Log.d("Available extensions", GLES20.glGetString(GLES20.GL_EXTENSIONS));
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, texW, texH, 0, GLES20.GL_RGB, GL_OES_texture_half_float, null);
    GLES20.glBindFramebuffer(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb[0]);
    GLES20.glFramebufferTexture2D(GLES20.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GLES20.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTex[0], 0);
```

results in the nexus 7 succeeding in framebuffer attachment whereas the kyocera fails, even though the neccessary extensions are listed as supported.

My question is is there an equivalent to half float that allows 16 bits of data per component of RGBA that is more widely supported than half_float?